# Perché non si può dire "conduttore di un veicolo" o "materiale conducente"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, etymology, difference

Ho osservato che:

- *Conducente* significa *ciò che conduce*, e viene usato in riferimento a chi guida - conduce - un veicolo (es. "Non parlare al conducente");
- Anche *conduttore* significa *ciò che conduce*, ma viene usato in riferimento a materiali che conducono energia termica o elettrica.

I due termini sembrano equivalenti; perché, allora, non si può dire *il conduttore di un veicolo* o *i metalli sono buoni conducenti*? È semplicemente una regola, o ci sono ragioni etimologiche/grammaticali che differenziano i due termini?

---

Tentando di risolvere il quesito ho osservato che *conducente*, essendo un participio presente, caratterizza il sostantivo a cui si riferisce nell'azione **presente** di condurre (ciò che sta conducendo), mentre *conduttore* lo caratterizza nell'azione **abituale** di condurre (ciò che è solito condurre, o che ha il ruolo di condurre).

Benché quest'osservazione chiarisca perché si dice *il rame è un buon conduttore* e non *un buon conducente*, ancora non spiega perché un autista di professione, perciò qualcuno che è solito condurre, sia chiamato *conducente*.

Comment: Se *il rame è un ottimo conduttore* è strano che *la ceramica sia un ottimo isolante* e non un *ottimo isolatore*.

Comment: Il *conduttore* del treno è il capotreno, il *conducente* è il macchinista. Il *conduttore* non ha nemmeno bisogno del veicolo, se è il *conduttore di un gregge*, mentre il *conducente* senza veicolo non ha senso.

Comment: ancora peggio, il "conduttore" di un appartamento è chi lo prende in affitto.

Comment: Negli incarichi militari EI: Conduttore: colui che guidava automezzi vari (18/a). Conducente: alpino addetto al mulo (21/a).

Comment: @DaG: E cosa sono "EI", "18/a" e "21/a"?

Comment: @Charo: EI è l'Esercito Italiano, 18/a e 21/a presumo siano codici identificativi dei vari incarichi.

Comment: Grazie, @GiulioMuscarello. Nel mio paese "EI" si usa per "Estado Islámico" o "Estat Islàmic".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Segnalo altri casi analoghi:

- *dirigente* / *direttore*
- *agente* / *attore*
- *docente* / *dottore*

In realtà vedo una sfumatura di significato diverso nelle due terminazioni, anche se sicuramente in molti casi si impone semplicemente un uso convenzionale. Lo dice lo stesso Giulio nella domanda: il conducente è chi si trova in quel momento a condurre, il conduttore è chi ha stabilmente il ruolo di condurre. In un caso abbiamo la funzione, nell'altro il ruolo.

Nel caso dei veicoli, la parola *conducente* non indica la professione dell'autista bensì chi in una data circostanza si trova al volante: se un malintenzionato dirotta un pullman obbligando l'autista a lasciare il posto di guida (un esempio davvero molto inverosimile, ma tant'è), diventa il conducente del mezzo. Un conduttore di elettricità può condurla oppure no, a seconda della differenza di potenziale che c'è ai suoi estremi, ma continua ad essere conduttore a prescindere dal fatto che in un dato momento sia conducente o non lo sia.

Un autista non si chiama *conduttore* perché si chiama già *autista*. Ma per esempio chi di professione conduce una trasmissione televisiva o radiofonica si chiama, per l'appunto, *conduttore*.

Naturalmente, la distinzione non opera sempre con coerenza perché i due significati sono davvero molto vicini. Per esempio, se è vero che *docente* è a rigore una funzione momentanea e non una professione (mi è capitato di tenere occasionalmente dei brevi corsi e in quella circostanza ero considerato il docente di quella lezione), è anche vero che il nome di chi lo fa di professione è *insegnante* che a logica dovrebbe essere esattamente la stessa parola...

Comment: Quindi l'_insegnante_ dovrebbe essere _insegnatore_ ;-) Comunque +1

Comment: Alcuni insegnanti però sono _professori_...

Answer (score 8):

Sono consuetudini d'uso, che vanno a orecchio e come tali possono cambiare nel tempo. D'Annunzio ancora poteva scrivere combattitore, e il battente della porta per quanto batta abitualmente non sarà accettabile come battitore, a differenza di un percussore che non sarà mai un percuotente, ecc. Per ogni "regola" si trovano subito due eccezioni, ma per fortuna non è necessario regolamentare tutto (anzi, quanti danni alla lingua ha fatto l'eccesso di regolamentazione stabilita a tavolino...).

Answer (score 3):

La preferenza a "conducente" sembra essere solo apparente e dovuta all'uso e ciò non implica un vero errore, ma solo acquiescenza all'abitudine.

*Conduttore* è usato da più tempo e forse è rimasto invariato per le forme di trasporto più antiche (vi è anche il conduttore di carro (*cfr. Cortelazzo-Zolli più in basso*).
A questo proposito su [gbooks](http://books.google.it/books?id=fL34CD4W1ZUC&dq=conducente%20conduttore%20-fisica&hl=it&pg=PA109#v=onepage&q=conducente%20conduttore%20-fisica&f=false) in una stessa pagina di una Raccolta degli atti del governo per il regno di Sardegna (1845) si fa riferimento a **conducente** (di *mulo, bestie, vettura, carrozza, carretta, carrettone*) e **conduttore** (di *barroccio*). Il barroccio era ed è un mezzo di trasporto di sole merci, senza spazio (in teoria) per sedersi "a cassetta" né sull'animale trainante.

Quindi il conduttore sarebbe colui che conduce "dall'esterno".
Ma tutto questo potrebbe essere una distinzione non generalizzabile in altri regni e stati d'Italia o, al peggio, una trovata del burocrate.

Dizionario etimologico, **Cortelazzo-Zolli**, Zanichelli
conducente,
s. m. *‘chi dirige una squadra d'operai, un gruppo d'artigiani’ (1513, Statuto dell'arte della seta), ‘guidatore d'un veicolo’ (1913, F. Paolieri)*

conduttore,
agg. e s. m. *‘che conduce, che guida’ (conducitore: av. 1294, Guittone; conduttore: 1304-08, Dante)*

s. m. *‘guidatore di veicoli’ (conducitore: sec. XIII, Novellino; conduttore: av. 1676, C. R. Dati), ‘corpo nel quale si può avere passaggio di calore, di elettricità’ (av. 1798, F. Milizia), ‘affittuario, locatario’ (1301-57, Form. not. ar.),*

http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conduttore/ (**Treccani**)
http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conducente/
http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/C/conduttore.aspx?query=conduttore (**Hoepli**)
http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/C/conducente.aspx?query=conducente
http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/conduttore.shtml (**Sabatini- Coletti**)
http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/conducente.shtml
http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/conduttore.php (**Hoepli**)
http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/conducente.php

Riguardo a "materiale/corpo conducente" non è improprio.
*Conducente* nella locuzione è un participio aggettivato, cfr. **resistore a corpo conducente** http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/resistore/).
È probabile che il  neologismo di Desaguliers (sempre **Cortelazzo-Zolli**: *"Il conduttore elettrico è l'“ingl. conductor: termine tecnificato da Desaguliers (1739)” (Migl. Onom.)*) pesi più della storia italiana nello studio dell'elettricità perché sempre su gbooks la locuzione "corpo conducente" scompare via via nel tempo:
[XIX](http://www.google.it/search?q=%22materiale%20conducente%22&btnG=Cerca%20nei%20libri&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=it#hl=it&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min:1800%2Ccd_max:1899&tbm=bks&q=%22corpo%20conducente%22)
[XX](http://www.google.it/search?q=%22materiale%20conducente%22&btnG=Cerca%20nei%20libri&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=it#q=%22corpo%20conducente%22&hl=it&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks)
XXI ...